# Is there a better way to optimize the program below?

Tags: c

Basicaly this program takes a decimal number from 1 to 10, that is the index of power of 2. And turns into an array with 2^n combinations. For example: If my number is 1, I'll have 2 arrays, [0] and [1], and if my decimal is 2, I'll have 4 combinations, [0 0]; [0 1]; [1 0]; [1 1]. And so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, q = 1, i, f, d, p, vet[10];

    scanf ("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        q *= 2;
    }
     n--;

    for (i = 0; i < q; i++){
        f = i;

        for (p = 0; p < 10; p++){   //setting array to 0
            vet[p] = 0;
        }

        while ( f > 0){
           p = 1;
           d = 0;

            while (f >= 2*p){
                p *= 2;
                d++;
            }

            vet[d] = 1;
            f -= p;
        }

        printf ("f: %d bin:", i);

        for (p = 0; p < 10; p++)
            printf ("%d", vet[9-p]);

        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take this to [codereview.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Code Review SE!

Comment: I'll post it on Code Review. New here, did not know there was such a web page. Tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n, q = 1, vet[10] = {0};

    scanf("%d", &n);
    q <<= n;

    for(;;){
        for(int i = n-1; i >= 0; --i)
            printf("%d", vet[i]);
        printf("\n");
        if(!--q)
            break;
        for(int i = 0, carry = 1, c; carry; ++i, carry = c){
            c = vet[i] & carry;
            vet[i] ^= carry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to write it without bitwise operators? Because I haven't learn it yet.

Comment: @IgorBraga E.g `c = vet[i] & carry; vet[i] ^= carry;` --> `c = vet[i] && carry; vet[i] = vet[i] != carry;`

Comment: What about `q <<= n`, is this also a bitwise operator?

Comment: @IgorBraga Sure, `int w[] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024};`, then `q <<= n;` --> `q = w[n];`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.